# UITableView cells are not selected after deleting last cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableView with 3 sections: 2 of the 3 are constants (each with only one cell that doesn't change) and the first section which you can add or remove from cells. everything works perfectly besides when deleting cells from this section: once i deleted the last cell, this cell disappears (as expected) but then the other sections are not functional, meaning, i cant click on them (they both load another view). if i load the app when the first section is empty in the first place, everything is fine. this thing happens only after deleting the last cell in this section. i tried to put logs everywhere in the code and everything looks ok.

Would appreciate any suggestion.

Here is some code that may be relevant. happy to provide more if needed:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    return YES;
 } else {
    return NO;
 }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tblSimpleTable beginUpdates];

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

     NSMutableArray * section = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];    
    [section removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //UPDATING USERS DEFAULTS
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];            
    [defaults setObject:section forKey:@"listOfAccessNumbers"];

    [tblSimpleTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [tblSimpleTable reloadData];


    }


}     
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {

...

}

[tblSimpleTable endUpdates];

}


- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

NSLog(@"****************** entering setEditing");

[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
[tblSimpleTable setEditing:editing animated:YES];
if (editing) {
     editButton.enabled = NO;
} else {
    editButton.enabled = YES;
}
}
```

UPDATE: adding more methods:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"****************** entering cellForRowAtIndexPath");

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; //try here diff styles
}


NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
array = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.196 green:0.3098 blue:0.52 alpha:1.0];

if (sectionIndicator == YES){

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

}
else
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
}


return cell;
}




 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return [listOfItems count];    
 }



 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [[listOfItems objectAtIndex:section] count];
 }
```

Comment: Are you handling the case properly in the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods?

Comment: You don't necessarily need the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` for the commitEditingStyle method. It would be worth a try to remove them and see if it fixes the problem. If it doesn't, the problem is most likely something associated with your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method or one of the dataSource methods since it is happening after you refresh the table

Comment: yes i do, but I am also not sure I understand the connection, cause the table is being drawn correctly (3 sections, one "empty" with no cells, and two sections (fixed) with one cell each).

Comment: @slev - removing beginUpdates and endUpdates indeed doesnt change anything, for good or bad.

Comment: also whats interesting is that after deleting the last cell, the cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called at all. just the setEditing is being called (see above update)

Comment: Well, if you remove the last cell in a section, it should be crashing as every section is required to have at least one cell in it.  If you want to remove the last cell, you should call `tableview:deleteSections:withRowAnimation` and then insert a section with `tableView:insertSections:withRowAnimation` when you add the first item.

Comment: even if removing the section altogether when the last cell is being deleted the other sections are still not responding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may know what's going on, so I'm going to post it as an answer.

I just noticed that you are calling for `listOfItems` to get the temp array which you remove the item from. I also see you are then updating an object in the `NSUserDefaults`. After this is done, is `listOfItems` also updated? If it isn't, that is where you problem lies. It will continue to hold all the same information as before, thus appearing as if there's no update occurring. I hope this is the case, because it will make for a very easy fix on your part. If it isn't, seeing your `dataSource` methods might be necessary to see where the problem might lie.

Comment: I was surprised too but "[section removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];" does remove the entry from listOfItems as well, so thats not the issue...thanks though

Comment: Very odd indeed. Any chance we can see your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods. If the `listOfItems` isn't the problem, I'm betting the issue would be in one of those methods

Comment: here you go, added all those methods. I dont think there is anything wrong there....still cant fix this, frustrating...:/

Comment: I'm sorry to hear it's still not fixed. And I agree there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the dataSource methods. The only other place I could think to look would be whatever method you have that updates `listOfItems` and the `tableView:didSelectRow...` method. I can definitely understand if you are getting tired of posting new methods, but I'm happy to keep trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `reloadData` inside `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`. You can always set a boolean flag to be true inside `beginUpdates` and check that flag after you call `endUpdates` to see if you should call `reloadData`, although I'm not sure why you need to call `reloadData`.

Comment: removing the reloadData doesnt help.